# Memory leak in TBXML iOS Parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I am using TBXML for XML feed parsing and instruments to detect memory leaks.

Instruments tells me there is a memory leak in function

```
- (TBXMLAttribute*) nextAvailableAttribute {
currentAttribute++;

if (!currentAttributeBuffer) {
currentAttributeBuffer = calloc(1, sizeof(TBXMLAttributeBuffer));
currentAttributeBuffer->attributes = (TBXMLAttribute*)calloc(MAX_ATTRIBUTES,sizeof(TBXMLAttribute));
currentAttribute = 0;
} else if (currentAttribute >= MAX_ATTRIBUTES) {
currentAttributeBuffer->next = calloc(1, sizeof(TBXMLAttributeBuffer));
currentAttributeBuffer->next->previous = currentAttributeBuffer;
currentAttributeBuffer = currentAttributeBuffer->next;
currentAttributeBuffer->attributes = (TBXMLAttribute*)calloc(MAX_ATTRIBUTES,sizeof(TBXMLAttribute));
currentAttribute = 0;
}

return &currentAttributeBuffer->attributes[currentAttribute];
}
```

at the line

```
currentAttributeBuffer->attributes = (TBXMLAttribute*)calloc(MAX_ATTRIBUTES,sizeof(TBXMLAttribute));
```

Does any one solved it before?

Comment: @Checkit I really haven't spent more time on debugguig it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEWARE.... instruments is telling you WHERE the leaked memory was originally created, NOT that the issue is in that line... for instance, if you do something with the attribute returned and leak it elsewhere, instruments will show THE line above, where it was created, NOT where you leaked it....

Answer (score 0):

`calloc` is a C function to allocate memory.  You should call `free currentAttributeBuffer;` when you're finished with it.  That will fix the memory leak.